# Headphones work but laptop speakers do not on 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, headphones

I am under Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I am unable to make my laptop speakers work even though when I put headphones it does. On Windows (I have a dual-boot), the speakers work.
Here are some information and steps that I have tried :

- `lspci -v` :

```
...
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
   DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
   Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1e02
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 209, IOMMU group 16
   Memory at 603f2c8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
   Memory at 603f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
   Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
   Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
   Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
   Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
...
```

- `lshw -C multimedia`:

```
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 F
       vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@3:8
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
       version: 0.03
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:209 memory:603f2c8000-603f2cbfff memory:603f000000-603f0fffff
```

- The sound is detected in `pavucontrol`:
  [image]
- I tried to upgrade [sof-bin](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin) to version 2.7.x to no avail.